# Creat 3d plot- equation (2 paramenters) time dependent ? matlab

Tags: matlab, surface

I have an equation
 **Z=a*exp(k*t)**
Is there any way to "plot" the result "Z" in function of variation on the parameters "k" and "a" AND along time?? 
 or to make a surface..Or I´ll always have to fixate on of the parameters?
cheers

Comment: it is a 4d graph which you can't show in a single plot!

Comment: have a look [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/visualizing-four-dimensional-data.html). Additionally, there is a function called [isosurface](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html) which you can use if you fix one of the parameters. Another idea is to use a regular surf plot and use color as a 4th dimension (e.g. you can choose `t` for this)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example with color coding the time axis

```
clear;close all;clc;

t=0:0.02:0.2;
k = 0:10;
a = 0:100;
[x, y] = meshgrid(k, a);

figure;
colorList = colormap(jet);
hold on;
for ii=1:numel(t)
    z=y.*exp(x.*t(ii));
    h = surf(x, y, z);
    set(h,'edgecolor','none','FaceColor',colorList(5*ii,:),'FaceAlpha',0.5);
end
hold off;

legend(cellstr(num2str(t', 't=%.2f')), 'location', 'northwest')
view([45 30]);
xlabel('k');
ylabel('a');
zlabel('Z');
```

and the result
[image: result]